# Python Polymorphism through inheritance and interface

Tags: java, python, interface, polymorphism

I am using Python 2.7 (google app engine)

Learning `Python`, I have figured out how the language uses inheritance to achieve polymorphism.

`INHERITANCE`-BASED POLYMORPHISM IN `PYTHON`:

```
class pet:
  number_of_legs = None
  age = None

  def sleep(self):
    print "zzz"

  def count_legs(self):
    print "I have %s legs." % self.number_of_legs
    return self.number_of_legs


class dog(pet):
  def bark(self):
    print "woof"

doug = dog()

doug.number_of_legs = 5;

print "Doug has %s legs." % doug.count_legs()
doug.bark()
```

My question is this: Does Python have loosely coupled polymorphism, i.e. using `interface` instead of `inheritance`. For example, in Java, classes with no ancestral relationships may implement the same interface. See `HouseDog` and `PetRock` in the following example.

`INTERFACE`-BASED POLYMORPHISM IN `JAVA`:

```
class Animal{
   int legs;
   double weight;

   public int getLegs(){return this.legs;}
   public double getWeight(){return this.weight}
}

interface Pet{
    public int getNumberOfDresses();
    public int getNumberOfToys();
}

class HouseDog extends Animal implements Pet{
   //... implementation here
}

class PetRock implements Pet{
   //a rock and a dog don't really have much in common.
   //But both can be treated as pets
}
```

QUESTION:

Again: Does python have an object-oriented way to achieve polymorphism without using inheritance?

Comment: Python never achieves polymorphism through inheritance. Inheritance is a way to reuse code which is defined such that the result plays well with polymorphism.

Comment: I suppose that's technically true. Thanks.

Comment: @kasavbere: What delnan says ist not just technically true. It is actually true.

Comment: It's probably also important to point out that the only reason Java has a concept of the `interface` is to avoid the complex semantics method calling in a multiple inheritance system.  From a perspective of typing, interfaces in Java *do* define ancestral relationships, just like classes.  It's just that they can't provide method inheritance to go with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they call it [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).  There's no need to formally implement an interface.  Java-style interfaces don't exist because Python has multiple inheritance, so if you want to define the interface, you just use a regular class as the supertype.  But, generally, people avoid creating completely abstract base classes, and avail themselves of duck typing.

For your example, one would just omit the `Pet` interface, but let `HouseDog` and `PetRock` both have `getNumberOfDresses` and `getNumberOfToys` methods.  In polymorphic situations, Python checks for the existence of the methods, *only when they are called*, instead of checking the types at compile-time (which doesn't exist) or load-time.  The big advantage is in letting you rapidly prototype without worry about the formalisms while your implementation isn't yet complete.

If you do want formal type-checking, you can get it in a number of ways, but none is officially sanctioned.

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks for the reply (up vote). But I will keep looking in case there is another way.

Comment: Another way to do what?  You can feel free to make a `Pet` class to act as an interface, it's just that it's not necessary.

Comment: Another way without the `try-catch` block shown in the `wiki`. Remember, I am very new to Python (less than a week). So I prefer to let my curiosity have the better of me and explore the possibilities. If I find no other way, that's okay. Also, thanks for editing your post.

Comment: I'm not sure what try-catch block you're referring to

Comment: @kasavbere: You don't need a try-catch-clause if you only pass valid arguments in just the same way as you do in bondage-and-disipline languages. Yes, in the face of invalid arguments those would complain at compile-time which Python does not, but no programmer I know of just passes arguments by trial-and-error until the compiler stops complaining. There are interesting things a static type system can do for you, (like pattern matching or generics), but nannying someone to ensure he doesn't pass invalid arguments is not one of these interesting things.

Comment: I would say that type-checking is more useful than just pattern matching or generics.  It also makes code more self-documenting, and I think it's quite useful for learning OOP.  I think there are legitimate issues with dynamic typing in large systems where you can't actually formally ensure code correctness.  I miss Java-style typing in some cases.  But I don't miss trying to figure out the correct generic types for complicated generic functions.  Overall, I agree with @pillmuncher: dynamic typing is one reason I've traded Java in for Python for most of my programming needs.